# stringr: I want to remove stray characters (up to two) flanked by a space on either side

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am having difficulty achieving the following with stringr: I want to remove stray characters (up to two) flanked by a space on either side. I cannot get stringr to give me good results without an error. Two examples are below. Thank you in advance.

```
string1<-'john a smith'
output1<-'john smith'
string2<-'betty ao smith'
output2<-'betty smith'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
gsub(" \\S{1,2} ", " ", c('john a smith', 'betty ao smith'))
# [1] "john smith"  "betty smith"
```

- `\\S` is a non-space character
- `{.}` allows for repeats of the preceding pattern; for instance

  - `{2,}` at least 2
  - `{,3}` no more than 3
  - `{1,2}` between 1 and 2

Same in `stringr`, since it's "just regex" :-)

```r
stringr::str_replace(c('john a smith', 'betty ao smith'), " \\S{1,2} ", " ")
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very simple. There may be alternatives, but I have a hard time thinking I'll need a different solution. Will accept in a few minutes.